# App extension name can't be identical to app name?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app called "name", and I go to File > New Target in Xcode, and chose a sharing extension, but when I try to give it a name which is identical to the app(container) name, I get an error message :

> The project “name” already contains a target named “name”. Please choose a different name.

But obviously I want your app name and extension name to be the same, (like other app extensions such as Pocket).

The extension name that I chose is the name that **actually** appears on the extension menu, and not the container app name .

How would I give them the same name?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

create a share extension with different name , in `info.plist`of share extension change the bundle display name to your app name.

Answer (score 4):

It's not saying that you can't have an extension of the same name. It says you can't have a *target* with the same name.

Create the target with a sensible name. How about "App Extension"?

Then in the Info.plist for the extension, you can give it the *display* name that you want.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Test App & added the Share Extension with a different name but after that I changed the name of the Share Extension Target's "Bundle Display Name"...

Answer (score 0):

### For Safari Extensions

If anyone is trying to figure out how to change the display name for a Safari App Extension, all you need to do is to go into the `manifest.json` and change the `"name"` field to whatever you'd like. ⤵︎

[image]